# Rails 3 create a route to nested independent page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have 3 levels of nesting.

routes.rb looks like this

```
    resources :clients do
       resources :departments do
         resources :tasks
       end
    end
```

I would like to create a custom path that looks like this

```
/clients/:client_id/departments/:department_id/tasks/data
```

I have tried adding the following

```
    resources :clients do
       resources :departments do
         resources :tasks
           member do
             get "data"
           end
       end
    end
```

This creates the route

```
/clients/:client_id/departments/:department_id/tasks/:task_id/data
```

How would I remove the :task_id part the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member route acts on a member, that's why it requires an id. A collection acts on a collection and so doesn't require an id.

```
resources :clients do
   resources :departments do
     resources :tasks do
       collection do
         get "data"
       end
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
resources :clients do
   resources :departments do
     resources :tasks
       get "data", :on => :collection
   end
end
```